# Bring a route to the top of the navigation stack

Tags: flutter, router

I have a action in my flutter app, which navigates to a named route like so:

```dart
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add_request');
              },
              splashColor: Theme.of(_selfContext).colorScheme.secondary,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.nature_people_rounded),
                title: Text("Add request"),
              )
```

However what I really want is the line `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add_request');` to be replaced by something like `Navigator.pushOrBringToTopNamed(context, '/add_request')`

i.e., I do not want to always create a new `Route` but instead bring an existing one to the top of the navigation stack if it exists already.

I did not find any proper way in doing so. Someone knows how to achieve such a thing in somewhat proper flutter?

Answer (score 2):

Using the new Navigator 2.0 (Flutter v1.22) you can now use the pages property to obtain a List of the stack.

You could extend the Navigator and handle custom events such as pop / push events depending on what you find in your stack.

This is a helpful [article](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) on the subject.

And this is the [official documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0jx0l4-xymph9O6zLaOY4d_f7YFpNWX_eGbzYxr9wY/edit) of the Navigator 2.0 from the Flutter team.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the links. I actually stumbled upon the article on medium. However, I was unsure about support in current stable / beta channels and also I was a bit like "hold on, thats really much boilerplate and concepts in order to do trivial routing". But if that's the only way, I will have to dig into that the next days. Just to make sure: Routing 1.0 does not provide a way to do that?

Comment: Officially, there is no way.
Off the top of my head, I would suggest looking into the RouteObserver & NavigatorObserver class, as they could help you with the current release (Navigator 1.0)
You could attach an observer to your flutter app and listen to the stack changes, manually register the stack in a variable that would persist throughout the app, and check whether to push / pop any screens to reach the desired outcome.
It could get messy, and I haven't tried such a method, but in my opinion it's worth a try.